# How to fix my LINQ to properly find strings from the list in string?

Tags: c#, list, linq

Few hours already I am struggling with LINQ that supposed to find cities from list of objects inside of list of addresses.

I have a list of `CityModel` objects, where:

```
public class CityModel
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public char CountryChar { get; set; }
    }
```

and list of `AddressModel` objects:

```
public class AddressModel
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public char CountryChar { get; set; }
    }
```

In both cases `CountryChar` is a first letter of country belongs to the `City` or `Address` properties. All strings and characters are parsed from `ToLower()`, so all of them are in lower cases.

Examples of `CityModel` object:

```
            cities.Add(new CityModel()
            {
                City = "singapore",
                CountryChar = 's'
            }); //Singapore in singapore
            cities.Add(new CityModel()
            {
                City = "anthony",
                CountryChar = 'u'
            }); //Anthony in United States
```

Two cases of `AddressModel` objects:

```
addressesM.Add(new AddressModel()
            {
                Address = "#20-06, gateway east, 152, beach road, singapore 189721",
                CountryChar = 's'
            });
            addressesM.Add(new AddressModel()
            {
                Address = "01-01, 8, anthony road, singapore 229957",
                CountryChar = 's'
            }); //note: Anthony
```

Idea of my LINQ is to find if any of the cities is a substring of my `Address` property in each of `AddressModel` object. If yes, then verify if `CountryChar` for `AddressModel` matches `CountryChar` for `CityModel`.

My LINQ:

```
foreach (AddressModel address in addressesM)
            {
                string city = "xxx";
                i++;

                Console.WriteLine(i + " z " + addresses.Count());

                CityModel tocompare = cities.Where(collectionOfCities => address.Address.IndexOf(collectionOfCities.City) >= 0 &&
                (address.Address[address.Address.IndexOf(collectionOfCities.City) - 1] == ' ' ||
                address.Address[address.Address.IndexOf(collectionOfCities.City) - 1] == ',') &&
                (address.Address[address.Address.IndexOf(collectionOfCities.City) + collectionOfCities.City.Length] == ' ' ||
                address.Address[address.Address.IndexOf(collectionOfCities.City) + collectionOfCities.City.Length] == ',') &&
                collectionOfCities.CountryChar == address.CountryChar).FirstOrDefault();

                if (tocompare != null)
                {
                    TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

                    tocompare.City = textInfo.ToTitleCase(tocompare.City);

                    city = tocompare.City;
                }

                output.Add(city);
            }
```

For the first case of my `AddressModel` LINQ works good. The problem occures, when inside of my second `AddressModel` there is a word "Anthony", and there is also a City called `Anthony`. In this case, after checking for rest of LINQ conditions for "Anthony" it adds to my `output` "xxx" string and moves to next `AddressModel` in the list.

**I have no idea how to do that after failing with "Anthony" city the program will test rest of cities in the list?**

**EDIT:**

some of the addresses may have post-codes containing digits and upper case letters, examples:

> Block 7, 1st-3rd Floors, 1690, Cailun Lu, Pudong Xinqu, Shanghai,
> 201203, China.
>
> 1st Floor, 6, quai Antoine-1er Le Ruscino, 98012 Monte
> Carlo, CEDEX, Monaco.
>
> 1, Dole Drive, Westlake Village CA 91362-7300,
> USA.
>
> Gratsos Building, 15, Eleftheriou Venizelou Street, 105 64
> Athens, Greece.

Some of the city names may have more than 1 words, examples:

> Fish Hawk
>
> Panama City
>
> La Verne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's organize `cities`; assuming that `(City, CountryChar)` combination is *unique* we can build a dictionary:

```
List<CityModel> cities = ...

Dictionary<(string city, char country), CityModel> citiesDict = cities
  .ToDictionary(item => (item.City, item.CountryChar), 
                item => item);
```

Then we have to invent city name(s) extraction (with possible *false positives*); probably, the *last* name (consequent `a..z` letter)
is a good choice (let's use *regular expressions* for this):

```
// will return "singapore"
IEnumerable<string> CityNames(string address) {
  string name = Regex.Match(
     address, 
   @"\b[a-z]+\b", 
     RegexOptions.RightToLeft | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    yield return name;
}
```

Or more lenient (*any* names, will return `"gateway"`, `"east"`, `"beach"`, `"road"`, `"singapore"`) implementation:

```
IEnumerable<string> CityNames(string address) {
  return Regex
    .Matches(address, @"\b[a-z]+\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value);
}
```

Then we can build the final *Linq* with a help of `SelectMany`:

```
List<AddressModel> addresses = ...

var result = addresses
  .SelectMany(item => CityNames(item.Address) // match all possible cities form address
     .Select(possibleCity => new { // actual city from possible city
        address = item,
        city    = citiesDict.TryGetValue((possibleCity, item.CountryChar),
                                          out var actualCity) 
          ? actualCity // Either Real City (if found), say, "singapore"
          : null       // null if not exits, say, "road"
      }))
  .Where(item => item.city != null); // Real City Only
```

**Edit:** The main difficulty here is to *extract* potential city names (*Natural language processing* in general case...). If you can guarantee that address parts (street, city, country etc.) are separated by comma `,` we can try `Split`:

```
  IEnumerable<string> CityNames(string address) {
    return address
      .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Select(item => Regex.Replace(item.Trim(), @"\s+", " ").ToLower())
      .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item));
  }
```

Now, for `"1st Floor, 6, quai Antoine-1er Le Ruscino, 98012 Monte Carlo, CEDEX, Monaco"` we'll have `"1st floor"` `"6"` `"quai antoine-1er le ruscino"` `"98012 monte carlo"`, `"cedex"`, `"monaco"`. Please, note, that `98012` added to `Monte Carlo`. If you want to *strip* numbers and have `"st floor"`, `"quai antoine-er le ruscino"` `"monte carlo"`, `"cedex"`, `"monaco"`

```
  IEnumerable<string> CityNames(string address) {
    return address
      .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Select(item => Regex.Replace(item, "[0-9]+", ""))
      .Select(item => Regex.Replace(item.Trim(), @"\s+", " ").ToLower())
      .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item));
  }
```

Comment: Your solution works great, thanks. I think that I am going to like LINQ. Only prolem is when I try to parse with city name containing more than 1 word. For example _New Singapore_. It will fail, if `Address` string is splitted for separated single words. And I am not sure how could I split addresses in this case (updated question). Please note, that address string may contain postal-codes with digits and letters.

Comment: @bakunet: sure, you can `Split` (if you can gurantee that address parts are separated properly by `,` and you don't have, say `"37 Nevsky pospect Saint-Petersburg"`)

Comment: Actually, after edit, it worked absolutelly fine. Spasiba!